# Given a boolean expression evaluated to True, find out which variable(s) were responsible.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Suppose you have a boolean expression(eg. A or B) with a certain number of boolean variables(taking values True or False). For a certain set of values of the variables, we know the expression evaluated to True.
Given the expression and the values of the variables, find which variables were responsible for it.
For example,
Case 1: The expression is **A or (B and C)**.
**A** = True, 
**B** = False,
**C** = True
The output will be **A**

Case 2: The expression is **A and (B or C)**.
**A** = True,
**B** = False,
**C** = True
The output will be **A, C**.

Case 3: The expression is **A and (B or C)**.
**A** = True,
**B** = True,
**C** = True
The output will be A, B, C

Case 4: The expression is **A or (B and (C or D))**.
**A** = True,
**B** = True,
**C** = False,
**D** = True
The output will be **A, B, D**.

I want to know how do I go about finding the output. What would be the logic or algorithm I would use?

Comment: That looks correct

Comment: I don't see how the problem is well defined. What would you expect the answer to be if the expression is **A and (B or C)** with the values **A = B = C = True**. It's clear to me that **A** still contributes to the truth value. Do both **B** and **C** contribute to the truth value? Is it either of them? If so, which ones?

Comment: @jwc845 In that scenario, all of A, B and C contribute to the truth value. Thanks for pointing it out. I will update the post.

Comment: @jwc845 Thanks to your comment, I was able to think of a solution to it. Breaking down the expression into smaller expressions helped devise a solution to it.

Comment: The question is still rather unclear. What I think you mean is that for a given assignment that makes a formula true, there may be variables whose truth value can be altered without falsifying the formula and those are the ones which aren't "responsible" for the truth of the formula under this assignment. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your general form equation to 
[sum of products form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form). Converting to this form is always possible. Once in this form you will have an equation that is a series of clauses composed of ANDs. All the clauses will be ORed together. For example a converted equation may look like (bars represent NOT):

($A$ and $B$ and $\bar C$) or ($B$ and $D$) or ($\bar B$ and $E$) or ($F$)

Note how this is an expression composed of 4 clauses. The clauses happen to have varying length.

Then we can look at each clause individually. Since the clauses are only composed of ANDs and NOTs it is possible to mechanically check if each clause is true based on the given values of the variables. Since this is sum of products form any clause resulting in a true value will cause the entire expression to be true, so the answer to your question is every variable which shows up in a clause which is true is "responsible" for the truth value of the entire equation.

With the given values: $A$ = True, $B$ = True, $C$ = False, $D$ = False, $F$ = True.

One can see that the first and fourth clauses are individually true. Therefore, $A, B, C, F$ are "responsible" for the truth value.